# in web3py, any function to call static?

Tags: web3py, uniswap

I want to use Uniswap V3 Quoter function, but it's a write function. I have to call static to avoid gas cost.

I don't see any static call in web3py documentation. Any suggestion? Thanks ahead！

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
    contractName.functions.xxxfunction(xxx,xxx,xx).call()
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

To call a function of a contract but not use gas like 'calStatic' in web3.js, you just don't sign the transaction to rpc.

```py
from web3 import Web3

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("rpc-url"))
contract=w3.eth.contract(address="0xcontract-address", abi=contract_json_abo)

# to callStatic function,example set()
contract.functions.set().call()

# to actually execute at evm
transaction=contract.functions.set().buildTransaction({
    'gas': 70000,
    'gasPrice': web3.toWei('1', 'gwei'),
    'from':'0xyour-address',
    'nonce': nonce
    })
private_key = "enter_your_key_here" 
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(transaction, private_key=private_key)
w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
```